# Is it safe to check users IP with logged in session IP

Tags: javascript, ajax, session, ip, server-side

I have a simple game written in JavaScript and the HTML5 canvas tag. I am using AJAX which sends data to the server and updates the database accordingly. The problem I have is that, I am validating everything on the server side, the user simply sends the ID in the AJAX request and everything happens based on the ID.

This I am happy with, the problem I have is that, users can manipulate data to their liking and send bad data (e.g. send someone else's ID) and the server will deal with that. So what if say, I am on my account and I send the ID to the server as usual and everything is okay, now say someone knows my ID or I tell them and they send that down.

They can both send the ID at the same time and it will work, because the ID to do the task is valid, however two users shouldn't be sending the data to the server.

In my database I have a 'LoginSession' table, which stores the user id, the signed in date, the signed out date and the IP. So when a user has signed in, I have their IP stored.

So the way I intend to tackle this task is to basically, when they send the server the ID, I will check to see if their current IP is the IP they signed in with, if it's not, do stuff.

So to my actual question now, is this a good way to go about doing this? Can their IP change mid-session for any reason or can a user change their IP to match an existing IP? Everything is stored in the DB and everything is validated on the server side, the only problem I have is that basically, users can "multi-log" in and cheat to gain faster points.

Comment: Usually IP addresses don't change that much. With cabled lines very rarely, with mobiles there may be some changes since there are a lot of devices, but usually they're behind a NAT, so the outwards IP doesn't really change. As long as you don't expect to get unique IPs I'd say this has low risk. Only if it's playable on mobile devices that might hop from WiFi to mobile to another WiFi it might cause some issues.

Comment: What is your server side technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a hash when the game session begin, store it as a cookie and use that. It can be based on something like the timestamp and the users actual ID. You can then enforce this using the players IP address. If the hash does not match the IP, challange the user, maybe force the user to login again, or invalidate the old hash and create a new for the user. Making sure that you only have one player providing data for that user.

Also, I wouldn't trust the IP alone, as it can be spoofed, or changed. You also have to take into consideration that many players may share the same IP Address.

You can also retrieve basic details on the clients system (e.g. OS and Browser version) from the [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). When you create the hash store those details along side the IP and anytime one of those details does not match, invalidate the hash. This would force the hacker to not only spoof the IP, but also spoof his browser (or have an identical setup to the client).

Comment: How unique is the session? Can users find out this session? Can sessions be manipulated? If I find out my session and tell someone else it, can they use it to gain access and force data to the server?

Comment: A user could manipulate it yes, but if you create a new session for each game, or login it should be very difficult, especially if you compare the IP against the hash. I'll include some additional steps you can take.

Comment: Good information, I will definitely have to do a little more research into this! I would up vote but I need 15 reputation!

Answer (score 0):

Try using session cookies for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Basically checking by IP it may work. But it's not reliable, since IP may change for a bunch of different reasons (depends on ISP network implementation eg. NAT, PAT, Proxy etc.)

As I understood no one can play the game without logging in first. So when they do log in (with username and password) you can associate them a UNIQUE generated SESSION ID by which you can identify if a specific user (by USER ID) is logged in or not and save them on DB.
Then, on each login you will check if that is trying to log in with some user (USER ID) that already is logged in (by checking the DB), and you will deny it (deny multiple logins from same user).
Moreover, most probably you will need to create some scheduled job to expire (delete) inactive sessions for a specified amount of time.